# Scaffolded Identity Razor Pages Forms don't submit unless there is a route parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

This happens on all the Scaffolded Identity Razor Pages that do not include a route parameter in the Form definition, but let's take the `ForgotPassword` one as an example:
Here is the `form` as defined on the scaffolded page:

```
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I click the `submit` button, nothing happens.  The browser dev tools confirm nothing happens.  The page does not submit to the server. (and yes, I have entered a valid email address; if I don't, then the jquery validation correctly displays the appropriate error messages.)

But I've found that if I change the form definition to include a route parameter, as follows:

`<form asp-route-unusedArg="SomeValue" method="post">`

then the `submit` button works fine, and the form is submitted to the server.  (Even though the `OnPostAsync` method defined by the server code does not expect a parameter at all; it is defined as `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()`).  The way I figured this out was to compare the form definition with that of the `Login` form, which was working fine, and had a route parameter for `returnUrl`.

What is going on here?  Why is the form not submitting unless I add a route parameter?

Comment: Is it an ASP.NET Core 3.x app? I did a test, which work as expected.

Comment: Yes, it's ASP.Net Core 3.1

Comment: You can try to create a new project and do a test, then check if scaffold Identity in that new project would cause same issue.